# DateTime.UtcNow is 4 hours ahead

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp

I have seen some answers about how to correct this. I have an object of type DateTime. I have assigned this object as shown below.

`obj.TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;`

I cannot seem to find the right combination or code manipulation to get the correct date and time. It is always exactly 4 hours ahead of what the current time is.

This software will be deployed in various timezones.

Is there any reliable way to ensure the timestamp will be accurate across all time zones. My server time settings are correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Your server will always be in the same timezone, so no.  You'll need to track your users timezones and convert the time on each request.

Comment: UtcNow gives you uneversal time around the globe, you can read about it online. If your UTC is ahead 4 hours other UTC, then one of you have clock set wrongly.

Comment: Just return it as UTC and let the client handle the conversion to local time from their side

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Comment: All computer internally store and transfer DateTiime as UTC.  When in-porting or exporting a DateTime from/to string the computer uses the TimeZone setting on the computer to convert the string to a Time.  The only time you need to convert is when data is collected in one timezone and then converted from a string in another timezone the time zone where the data is collected must be used.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but...

```
var localDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx

Read the notes in the MSDN article.  This isnt't foolproof.  But, if you are looking for a way to get the server time, this is a quick and easy way to get about as close as you can w/o getting too crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question! Dates and times are a notoriously hard problem to solve. It seems so simple, yet it's so difficult to actually do. We're all so used to looking at our watches for the time, when in fact it's a lot harder than that once you get time zones and daylight saving involved.

Take a look at the excellent [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library. Even if you don't use it, the user guide provides some great insights into why dates and times are so hard a problem to solve.

I suspect your particular problem is related to the fact that your time zone is Eastern Time which is currently observing daylight saving, making your time zone 4 hours behind UTC.

In order to present the time to your users you'll need to know what time zone *they* are in. If they're in New York then you'll need to use `UTC-04:00`, if they're in California you'll need to use `UTC-08:00` and if they're in New Delhi you'll need to use `UTC+05:30`.

However, this could change if/when they stop observing daylight saving, but be careful here as there is no hard-and-fast rule for this. Eastern Time stops observing daylight saving on the first Sunday in November, British Time stops on the last Sunday in October, Indian Time has no daylight saving at all and Southern Hemisphere regions observe daylight saving in the winter months (at least from the perspective of Northern Hemisphere regions).

Good luck!